# PHP/mySQL: How do a concatenate a variable in a mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, concatenation

What is the proper way to concatenate text and a variable in PHP inside a mysql_query? Here is my attempt:

```
page.'$pageID'
```

I want it to output `page3`.

Here is all of the code (simplified to focus on the mysql_query):

```
if ($_POST['pageProgress']) {
        $pageProgress = $_POST['pageProgress'];
        $pageID = 3;
        $userID = 1;
        $updateUserProgress = mysql_query("UPDATE test SET page.'$pageID'='$pageProgress' WHERE userID='$userID'") or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

All of the code works perfectly if I simply replace `page.'$pageID'` with `page3`.

Comment: Please read about SQL injections and prepared statements in PHP. You are about to add a huge security vulnerability to your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not need the `.`. PHP parses double quoted (`"`) strings and replaces the variables with their values. As such:

```
$pageID = 3;
echo "UPDATE test SET page$pageID = '$pageProgress' WHERE userID = '$userID'";
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/uIdqqH

Comment: While `page" . $pageID . "` does work, I prefer your method. I think it is much cleaner and it works!

Comment: I also find it much cleaner than the mess with the dot operator. Remember though that it will only work with double quoted string like `"this"` and not single quoted string like `'that'`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your .'$pageID' is inside the double-quoted string; you don't concatenate this on the MySQL side; it gets parsed long before MySQL ever sees it.

It might be that you were trying to escape the field name for Mysql, in that case, you use backticks.

Try:

```
'UPDATE test SET `page'.$pageID.'`=\''.$pageProgress.'\' WHERE...'
```

Or, much easier on the eyes:

```
"UPDATE test SET `page{$pageID}`='{$pageProgress}' WHERE..."
```

Comment: I haven't tried this solution yet. I went with Xeon06's solution: `page$pageID`. I think it is a bit cleaner. Thank you for your answer though!

Comment: If it's useful, you can give it a +1 even if you accept Xeon's answer, which is also fine. You should get in the habit of escaping your field names in MySQL with backticks, and also need to give serious thought to @Phillippe_Gerber's notes about escaping your variables (check out [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.mysql-real-escape-string.php&ei=qwDMTtbOA-Sg2AXSjKnIDw&usg=AFQjCNHeZ7lbY5LQwaxER94luYHu89AmpA))

Comment: Thank you for your additional comment. I understand using `mysql_real_escape_string()`, but what is the purpose of escaping the field names?

Comment: When you get into utilizing variables in place of hard coded text, escaping is always a great idea. You might later expand this to work against multiple tables, import a table from a SQL Server or Oracle setup, or unassumingly add a reserved word as a field name (like `case` or `current_user` or `group`). These are easy to find if your field name is hard coded, since you will know the first time you run the function. However, with a variable field name, you may not discover this until production when the name fails (unless it is escaped).

Comment: I run into this issue frequently with products that support multiple databases (it becomes difficult to find field names that don't conflict with at least one).

Answer (score 1):

`"UPDATE test SET page".$pageID."='".$pageProgress."' WHERE userID='".$userID."';"`

Dots are in the wrong spot to do it with PHP's string functions.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE test SET page" . $pageID . " = '" . $pageProgress . "' WHERE userID = " . $userID)
```

Comment: This does work, but I prefer Xeon06's solution: `page$pageID`. Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mysql_query('UPDATE test SET page'.$pageID.'='.$pageProgress.' WHERE userID='.$userID)
```

Comment: I tried using your method with single quotes, but it didn't work for me. It did work though with double quotes. I used Xeon06's solution: `page$pageID`. Thank you for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$updateUserProgress = mysql_query("UPDATE test SET page".$pageID." = '".$pageProgress."' WHERE userID='".$userID."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

@Marc B ; that's not the question..

Comment: Correct! I like the way you think.

Comment: This does work, but I prefer Xeon06's solution: `page$pageID`. Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to concatenate anything. you do need to sanitize your variable from post though.

```
   if ($_POST['pageProgress']) {
    $pageProgress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pageProgress']);
    $pageID = 3;
    $userID = 1;
    $updateUserProgress = mysql_query("UPDATE test SET page$pageID='$pageProgress' WHERE   userID='$userID'") or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It will be sanitized!